# How to add pie menu so it will load next time I start with blender

Tags: python, scripting, pie-menu

How can I add this pie menu from text editor to blender(2.78) so it will load every time. Script kiddie here so please explain in plain English.

```
import bpy
from bpy.types import Menu


class VIEW3D_PIE_template(Menu):
    # label is displayed at the center of the pie menu.
    bl_label = "Select Mode"
    bl_idname = "mesh.kkmodeling"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout

        pie = layout.menu_pie()
        # operator_enum will just spread all available options
        # for the type enum of the operator on the pie
        #pie.operator_enum("mesh.select_mode", "type")
        pie.operator("view3d.edit_mesh_extrude_move_normal", text="Extrude Region")
        pie.operator("view3d.edit_mesh_extrude_individual_move", text="Extrude Individual")
        pie.operator("mesh.inset", text="Inset Faces")
        pie.operator("mesh.edge_face_add")
        pie.operator("mesh.subdivide")
        pie.operator("mesh.loopcut_slide")
        pie.operator("mesh.offset_edge_loops_slide")
        pie.operator("mesh.knife_tool", text="Knife")
def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(VIEW3D_PIE_template)

    wm = bpy.context.window_manager
    km = wm.keyconfigs.addon.keymaps.new("Mesh")
    kmi = km.keymap_items.new("wm.call_menu_pie", "W", "PRESS", shift=True, alt=True).properties.name="mesh.kkmodeling"


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(VIEW3D_PIE_template)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()

    bpy.ops.wm.call_menu_pie(name="VIEW3D_PIE_template")
```

Answer (score -1):

load py from preferences addon tab. Then activate add on.

Comment: Won't work with this code above. Please explain why, thanks!